# Error 404 page not displayed in production mode on Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, exception, symfony5

I am trying to customize a 404 page but it only appears in dev mode. When I switch to production mode, the Symfony exception page is displayed with the message No route found for “GET http://127.0 .0.1:8000/xxxxxxxx”.

My cache was emptied, I performed several commands including “composer dump-env prod” which added a .env.local.php file I also modified my Controller but nothing to do. Several files were checked including NotFoundHttpException.php, HttpException.php, debug_prod.php, “console” file in “Bin” folder, routes.yaml, RouterListener.php and other files.

here is the result I am looking for:
[default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUOwZ.png)

but here is what I have:
[exception page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kUe2.jpg)

I really need your help please, thanks in advance.

here is my routes.yaml file

`index: path: / controller:App\Controller\DefaultController::index`

Comment: Looks like your in your "production" you have  "debug: 1" and "env: dev" in your `.env`#

Comment: In my .env file I am in prod mode "APP_ENV=prod" and I added a line just below which is: APP_DEBUG=0. I tried with and without the line app debug it still does not work (my cache is deleted each time before each refresh).

Comment: the "exception page" is definatly the web_profiler check your app/config/packages/prod and dev folder for the configuration, looks like web_profiler is activated for prod

Comment: here is my web_profiler.yaml file in the folder package:
`when@dev:
    web_profiler:
        toolbar: true
        intercept_redirects: false

    framework:
        profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

when@test:
    web_profiler:
        toolbar: false
        intercept_redirects: false

    framework:
        profiler: { collect: false }
`

Comment: ok, maybe try to put this file into `app/config/packages/dev` so it is only configured for your dev environment, i´m not sure though, but you should be able to achieve what you want by removing web_profiler.yaml in the worst case

Comment: sry i forget to say that the file looks actually okay, maybe define a `when@prod`

Comment: I defined the when@prod in the web_profiler file like this : 
`when@prod:
  web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

  framework:
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }`

and i have this error : 
Container extension "web_profiler" is not registered in C:\wamp64\www\NEWPLANTE-2\config/packages/web_profiler.yaml (which is being imported from "C:\wamp64\www\NEWPLANTE-2\src\Kernel.php").

Comment: Hello everyone, I tried all the means that you mentioned to me but my error is still not solved. Do you have any other ideas for me? Please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your 404 template has itself an error. Remove all its content and start fresh with some simple text. If it works, begin adding old content until it breaks again. You'll know what is the issue.